# alternatives to long-running `find` command in unix

Tags: unix, optimization, find, delete-file, locate

I want to delete files that are older than 7 days, and I'm using this command to do so:

```
find /directory -mtime +7 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

It is working fine except it takes too long. Is there any other way to delete files older than 7 days, e.g. without using `find`?

Comment: You should probably restrict the search to files (`-type f`).  That might speed things up a bit as well.  It would probably also help speed things up if you could provide the `find` command with a list of specific places to look, e.g. `find /directory/a /directory/b -type f ...`. Also, you don't mention which OS you are using. It might also be helpful if you identify which `find` you are using.  (Have you tried `GNU find`?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using "-exec rm" is known to slow things down.  If your `find` has the -delete option, then try using it instead, like so:

```
find /directory -type f -mtime +7 -delete
```

If your `find` does not have the -delete option, then consider using GNU find (which might already be available on your system as `gfind`).

There are other possibilities, e.g. using `xargs`.  For further discussion and some other options, see [Deleting-Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Deleting-Files.html).

Answer (score 0):

Change the final `;` for a plus sign `+`

```
$ find /directory -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm -f {} \+
```

or use `xargs` command:

```
$ find /directory -type f -mtime +7 | xargs rm
```

Both will be at least 3 times faster